# Deleting complex array element

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

So I want to delete an array element from a JSON array based on an id in a sub-array. I know it sounds weird. Here's an example of the array. I want to delete the entire array [0] based on the [dealer][id] array where the [id] = 20220 in this example.

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [offset] => 1
            [length] => 15
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [dealer] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 20220
                                    [name] => apple
                                )
                        )
                 )
        )


}
```

In reality there are a lot more elements in the [results] array. I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this really a JSON array? You do have a closing curly brace... but no opening curly brace. Regardless of whether it's JSON or not... it's invalid.

Comment: My bad, it is an API call that I is a JSON array but I do this: $result = json_decode($response, true); to change it to a regular array . Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Loop thru data key first then check if dealer id matches the searched id

```
$id = 20220;

foreach ($array['results']['data'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['dealer']['id'] == $id) {
        unset($array['results']['data'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter,

```
$array['results']['data'] = array_filter($array['results']['data'], function($v){return $v['dealer']['id'] != 20220;});
```